# Read text file, create new rows by separator

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to import a text file as a data frame as a single column and multiple rows. I want a new row created for every sentence and I want to repeat the process for every word.

Like this.

> Mr. Trump has been leading most national polls in the Republican presidential contest, but he is facing a potentially changed landscape. With the Iowa caucuses less than three months away, attention has shifted to national security in the wake of the terrorist attacks in Paris last week. While the Republican electorate so far has favored political outsiders like Mr. Trump and Ben Carson, the concerns over terrorism and the arrival of refugees from Syria into the United States could change things.

should be read as

> V1
>
> [1] Mr
>
> [2] Trump has been leading most national polls in the Republican presidential contest, but he is facing a potentially changed landscape
>
> [3] With the Iowa caucuses less than three months away, attention has shifted to national security in the wake of the terrorist attacks in Paris last week
>
> [4] While the Republican electorate so far has favored political outsiders like Mr
>
> [5] Trump and Ben Carson, the concerns over terrorism and the arrival of refugees from Syria into the United States could change things

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
strsplit(txt, '[.]\\s*')[[1]]
```

#### data

```
txt <- "Mr. Trump has been leading most national polls in the Republican presidential contest, but he is facing a potentially changed landscape. With the Iowa caucuses less than three months away, attention has shifted to national security in the wake of the terrorist attacks in Paris last week. While the Republican electorate so far has favored political outsiders like Mr. Trump and Ben Carson, the concerns over terrorism and the arrival of refugees from Syria into the United States could change things."
```

Comment: Or `trimws(strsplit(txt, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]])`